# Inter-island ferries in Cabo Verde?

Tags: ferries, cape-verde

I'm visiting Cabo Verde in November, arriving at Sal. I'm hoping to visit a few of the other islands, preferably by ferry.

[CVInterilhas](https://www.cvinterilhas.cv) runs between some of the islands, but their schedule appears to be in flux. And, though a few weeks ago they advertised a route leaving Sal for Praia via Boa Vista, now, they seem to not mention this route at all.

I'm aware of two older similar questions ([1](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42506/how-to-travel-between-the-islands-of-cape-verde), [2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92971/getting-around-cape-verde-islands-from-sal)), but this information seems particularly prone to change.

SkyScanner [lists flights for around 75 euros](https://www.skyscanner.nl/transport/vluchten/sid/rai/191110/?adults=4&children=0&adultsv2=4&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home#/), one way.

CVInterilhas is not picking up its listed phone number and has not responded to email enquiries.

I prefer taking ferries between the islands. But, where can I get reliable information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two weeks in Cabo Verde, I can say that the best and only source on inter-island ferries is the CVInterilhas website.

Annoyingly, they update their immediate schedule sometimes only a few days in advance.